# Different descriptions with image and text for the variations of a product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying for some time to do the following in wordpress woocommerce
When a variable product is made, I want to upload different descriptions compared to the main product description. The variation itself has a separate description, but it only allows you to enter text, not images. If it is possible to change the description field into a field that also accepts images, the problem would be solved.
I tried with different plugins, there are 2 solutions on the internet (REMICORSON, businessbloome) but both solutions lead me to the same point, my need is to be able to insert image and text in the description of each variation of the product.

For image variation I use the "Extra Variation Images" plugin. In conclusion, please if someone can help me to change the description field of the existing product variation into a field where I can upload images and text or a plugin or a solution like his (businessbloome - Add Custom Field to Product Variations ) from the internet but with the possibility of adding an image. Thanks .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

there is a long and tricky option you can use html markup in the variation description for images and use css for styling[image: woocommerce variable product description]

Comment: This is a solution, but considering that this field will be captured by an API to be reposted, I wouldn't want it to somehow capture my div and not the image. I would like a safer solution if possible, thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).